# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check? Access to XMLHttpRequest at backend from frontend has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

This is the error that i'm stuck at
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://btesting.near8.io/userstr/str' from origin 'https://near8testing-react-app-222d7a.spheron.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
Where [btesting.near8.io](https://btesting.near8.io) is the deployed backend url. And This is the [deployed testing frontend](https://near8testing-react-app-222d7a.spheron.app/) of my project.

These are the methods i've implemented to resolve this error, but still stuck:

1. In backend(express), in index.js
   (i)

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.options("*", cors());
app.use(cors());
```

(ii)

```
// define allowCrossDomain middleware
const allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
};

// use allowCrossDomain middleware
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

And
2) In frontend(react), in the file where we are fetching data from the beackend:

```
const xyz = await axios.get(`${BACKEND_URL}/userstr/str`, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "*/*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token",
        },
      });
```

I believe i've implemented all the needed steps but still stuck. Let me know if i'm doing something wrong or i should do something else.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure so I'll brainstorm a little but maybe you shouldn't set any Access-Control-Allow headers in the last part that you shared. It might work not passing them in axios req. Also maybe, you can try a proxy server like https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware to bypass restrictions of cors. In this page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin) they stated that "*" value shouldn't be used with private apis. Please let me know after you give it a try

Comment: 1. You should read about CORS's so-called [wildcard exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards). 2. None of those `Access-Control-Allow-*` belong in a request, since they're _response_ headers. 3. Adding a `Content-Type` header to a `GET` request doesn't make much sense, since `GET` requests are not meant to have a body.